# exception 'Exception' with message 'Error: _makeCall() - cURL error: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to api.instagram.com:443

Tags: magento1.9.0.1

I download Neklo_Instagram Extension for retrieve Instagram Feed on my store. Extension install perfectly. but I am not able to get Images from the Instagram.

When I see `log` then It's giving me error like below:

```
2018-03-08T10:48:58+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Exception' with message 'Error: _makeCall() - cURL error: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to api.instagram.com:443 ' in G:\xampp\htdocs\mcardles\app\code\community\Neklo\Instagram\Model\Instagram\Api.php:647
Stack trace:
#0 G:\xampp\htdocs\mcardles\app\code\community\Neklo\Instagram\Model\Instagram\Api.php(145): Neklo_Instagram_Model_Instagram_Api->_makeCall('users/search', Array)
#1 G:\xampp\htdocs\mcardles\app\code\community\Neklo\Instagram\Model\Instagram.php(103): Neklo_Instagram_Model_Instagram_Api->searchUser('https://www.ins...')
#2 G:\xampp\htdocs\mcardles\app\code\community\Neklo\Instagram\Block\Widget\Feed.php(128): Neklo_Instagram_Model_Instagram->getUserMediaByName('https://www.ins...', '5')
#3 G:\xampp\htdocs\mcardles\app\code\community\Neklo\Instagram\Block\Widget\Feed.php(87): Neklo_Instagram_Block_Widget_Feed->_getUserMediaByName()
#4 G:\xampp\htdocs\mcardles\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\neklo_instagram\widget\feed.phtml(4): Neklo_Instagram_Block_Widget_Feed->getImageList()
#5 G:\xampp\htdocs\mcardles\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(241): include('G:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#6 G:\xampp\htdocs\mcardles\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend\\base\\d...')
#7 G:\xampp\htdocs\mcardles\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#8 G:\xampp\htdocs\mcardles\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#9 G:\xampp\htdocs\mcardles\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#10 G:\xampp\htdocs\mcardles\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(577): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('ba7852207f97dd7...', true)
#11 G:\xampp\htdocs\mcardles\app\code\core\Mage\Page\Block\Html\Wrapper.php(52): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('', true, true)
#12 G:\xampp\htdocs\mcardles\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(919): Mage_Page_Block_Html_Wrapper->_toHtml()
#13 G:\xampp\htdocs\mcardles\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#14 G:\xampp\htdocs\mcardles\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('footer_before', true)
#15 G:\xampp\htdocs\mcardles\app\design\frontend\mcardles\newchange\template\page\1column.phtml(58): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('footer_before')
#16 G:\xampp\htdocs\mcardles\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(241): include('G:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#17 G:\xampp\htdocs\mcardles\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend\\mcardl...')
#18 G:\xampp\htdocs\mcardles\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#19 G:\xampp\htdocs\mcardles\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#20 G:\xampp\htdocs\mcardles\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#21 G:\xampp\htdocs\mcardles\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#22 G:\xampp\htdocs\mcardles\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\Helper\Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#23 G:\xampp\htdocs\mcardles\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\Helper\Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#24 G:\xampp\htdocs\mcardles\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\controllers\IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#25 G:\xampp\htdocs\mcardles\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#26 G:\xampp\htdocs\mcardles\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#27 G:\xampp\htdocs\mcardles\app\code\community\BalkeTechnologies\StoreMaintenance\Controller\Router\Standard.php(91): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#28 G:\xampp\htdocs\mcardles\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): BalkeTechnologies_StoreMaintenance_Controller_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#29 G:\xampp\htdocs\mcardles\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#30 G:\xampp\htdocs\mcardles\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#31 G:\xampp\htdocs\mcardles\index.php(90): Mage::run('', 'store')
#32 {main}
```

I am using Magento Version:`1.9.0.1`

Can any one help me?Any kind of help will appreciate.

Comment: Maybe you should contact the Neklo_Instagram Extension support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Googled very much and I found that there is `TLS` issue in `Curl.php` file which is located under `/downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client` folder.

Edit `Curl.php` file:

First find this line : `$this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);`

and add one line after above line:

```
$this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');
```

Clear `cache` and my problem solved.